# Kendo UI - Unable to get GBP £ currency symbol with the LOCALE_ID en-GB

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Following the example in the Kendo UI for Angular 2 docs for Internationalization, I am able to change my Applications culture and currency to bg-BG just like in their example. The setup can be seen [in there docs](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/internationalization/) and [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7jnQLgwTNPwcfWCf6Gik?p=preview).

I would like to get my App to use the en-GB and therefore use £ rather than the default $. But when I change the LOCALE_ID to en-GB and load in the cldr **en** data I just get dollars. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lZsuBeNSEr8vk1PTzdjO?p=preview)

Has anyone been able to get the £ symbol and know what I am missing?

Here is the app.module.ts:

```
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

import { load, IntlModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';

load(require("cldr-data/main/en/numbers.json"),
     require("cldr-data/main/en/currencies.json"),
     require("cldr-data/main/en/ca-gregorian.json"),
     require("cldr-data/main/en/timeZoneNames.json"),
     require("cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
     require("cldr-data/supplemental/currencyData.json"),
     require("cldr-data/supplemental/weekData.json"));

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, IntlModule ],
  providers:    [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-GB' }
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: can you post your html/xml code?

Answer (score -1):

This will work: 
`{{numericalValue|currency:'GBP':true:'0.2-2'}}`

`numericalValue` is the variable you want to display

`|` tells the binding that it's a pipe

`currency` tells it to use the currency pipe

`'GBP'` determines the currency

`true` uses the symbol not ISO code

`'0.2-2'` determines how many numbers to display minimum

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to determine the currency based on the locale. Different users will be located in different countries so hard coding GBP is not an option. It may be a bug in Kendo as it works for both German and Bulgarian locales but not UK.

Comment: so you downvoted me because you didnt specify something in your question? really?

Comment: The title specifies to get £ using Locale Id en-GB. You bypassed en-GB entirely.

Comment: but you didnt specify that you wanted other currencies as well

Comment: and how do you actually display the symbol without using the currency pipe? you need to use the true property in the currency pipe to display the symbol and not the currency code